# Passing char as an argument in C/C++ to replace particular letters in a word

Tags: replace, char, c-strings

I have an array of chars (c-string), which I iterate through with for loop.
I want to replace particular letters with another symbolols - chars, particularly '*' and '/'. I have a function that checks if the letter is to be omitted

```
    bool omit_letter(char ch){
    if(ch=='W' || ch == 'w' || ch=='Y'|| ch=='y'|| ch=='H'|| ch=='h'){
    return true;
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
    }
```

and another function that checks if the letter is a vowel:

```
bool isVowel(char ch){
if (ch=='a' || ch=='A' || ch=='e' || ch=='E' || ch=='i' || ch=='I' || ch=='o' || ch=='O' || ch== 'u' || ch=='U'){
return true;
}
else {return false;}
}
```

In the main method I call these functions in the for loop:

```
    int size_cstr=strlen(m);
    int br=0;
    char vowel ='*';
    char omit='/';
    char temp;
    for(int k=1;k<size_cstr;k++){
    temp=m[k];
    if(isVowel(temp)){
        m[k]=vowel;
        br++;

    }

        if(omit_letter(temp)){
        m[k]='/';
    }
    else{
    replace_let(temp);
    }
        }
```

But when I print the c-string in the end (to check whether the correspondng letters have been replaced with '*' and '/'), the letters remain the same.
What am I doing the wrong way?

Comment: I tried you code on replit ... Seems to work.  couldn't use bool had to use typedef... https://repl.it/repls/FlakyQuarrelsomePanda   Maybe you can post more of the code to troubleshoot further.